# MongoDs in ReplSet won't start after trying out some MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I was practicing some MapReduce inside of my Primary's mongo shell when it suddenly became a Secondary. I SSHed into the two other VM's with the other secondaries, and discovered that the mongod's had been rendered inoperaple. I killed them and I issued the `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` to kick them off and I entered the `mongo` shell. After a few seconds they were interrupted with:

```
2014-09-14T22:29:54.142-0500 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2014-09-14T22:29:54.143-0500 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2014-09-14T22:29:54.143-0500 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-09-14T22:29:54.143-0500 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>
```

This is from their (the two original secondaries in the replicaset) logs:

```
2014-09-14T22:09:21.879-0500 [rsBackgroundSync] replSet syncing to: vm-billing-001:27017
2014-09-14T22:09:21.880-0500 [rsSync] replSet still syncing, not yet to minValid optime 54165090:1
2014-09-14T22:09:21.882-0500 [rsBackgroundSync] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to vm-billing-001:27017
2014-09-14T22:09:21.886-0500 [rsSync] replSet SECONDARY
2014-09-14T22:09:21.886-0500 [repl writer worker 1] build index on: test.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1_inc properties: { v: 1, key: { 0: 1 }, name: "_temp_0", ns: "test.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1_inc" }
2014-09-14T22:09:21.887-0500 [repl writer worker 1]      added index to empty collection
2014-09-14T22:09:21.887-0500 [repl writer worker 1] build index on: test.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1 properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "test.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1" }
2014-09-14T22:09:21.887-0500 [repl writer worker 1]      added index to empty collection
2014-09-14T22:09:21.888-0500 [repl writer worker 1] build index on: test.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1 properties: { v: 1, unique: true, key: { id: 1.0 }, name: "id_1", ns: "test.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1" }
2014-09-14T22:09:21.888-0500 [repl writer worker 1]      added index to empty collection
2014-09-14T22:09:21.891-0500 [repl writer worker 2] ERROR: writer worker caught exception:  :: caused by :: 11000 insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: cisco.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1.$id_1  dup key: { : null } on: { ts: Timestamp 1410748561000|46, h: 9014687153249982311, v: 2, op: "i", ns: "cisco.tmp.mr.CCS.nonconforming_1", o: { _id: 14, value: 1.0 } }
2014-09-14T22:09:21.891-0500 [repl writer worker 2] Fatal Assertion 16360
2014-09-14T22:09:21.891-0500 [repl writer worker 2]
```

I can issue `mongo --host ... --port ...` from both of the two VMs that can't start the mongo to the original primary mongo, but I do see some connection refused notes above in the error log.

My original primary mongod can still be connected to in the `mongo` shell, but it is a primary. I can kill it and restart it and it will start up in secondary.

How can I roll back to the last known state and restart my replica set?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? There were bugs with temporary map/reduce collections being inappropriately replicated to secondaries ([SERVER-13981](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13981)). This might be related. You should drop the temporary map/reduce collections.